# Subtrair data e exibir em ANOS, MESES e DIAS

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, sql-select, select

SGBD: MySQL

Problema: Como retornar a substração da data atual com uma data específica e retornar o valor em ANOS, MESES e DIAS em uma consulta?

Exemplo:

```
DADOS
DataAdmissao    dataAtual
2010-04-07      2014-06-27 (este dado não está armazenado, seria utilizando a função "NOW()")

RESULTADO
"4 ANOS, 2 MESES e 20 DIAS"
```

Comment: Você pode utilizar as funções **DATEDIFF** e **DATE_FORMAT** do mysql [Mysql Date and Time Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

Comment: Idealmente, por design, tu não usaria o SGBD pra isso, já que a solução tende a ficar presa ao SGBD em uso e o resultado pode não ser tão elegante quanto o esperado. Não sendo possível, convém usar uma UDF no lugar de jogar o processo todo nas consultas.

Comment: Caso alguém se interesse por uma solução SQL Server: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/22856/70

Answer (score 6, accepted):

***Tabela Exemplo***

```
CREATE TABLE tablexemplo(
    DataAdmissao date
  );

INSERT INTO tablexemplo(DataAdmissao) values('2010-04-07');
INSERT INTO tablexemplo(DataAdmissao) values('2010-04-08');
INSERT INTO tablexemplo(DataAdmissao) values('2010-04-09');
INSERT INTO tablexemplo(DataAdmissao) values('1980-06-28');
INSERT INTO tablexemplo(DataAdmissao) values('2010-06-30');
INSERT INTO tablexemplo(DataAdmissao) values('2010-06-28');
INSERT INTO tablexemplo(DataAdmissao) values(current_date);
```

***SQL***

```
SELECT 
   date_format(DataAdmissao,'%d/%m/%Y') as DataAdmissao, 
   date_format(current_date,'%d/%m/%Y') as DataHoje, 
   Anos, 
   Mes, 
   Dias, 
   Concat(Anos, ' Anos ', Mes, ' Mes e ', Dias, ' Dias') AS Extenso
FROM (
    SELECT  
        DataAdmissao,
        TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, DataAdmissao, current_date) as Anos,
        TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, DataAdmissao + INTERVAL TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,  DataAdmissao, current_date) YEAR , current_date) AS Mes,
        TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, DataAdmissao + INTERVAL TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH,  DataAdmissao, current_date) MONTH , current_date) AS Dias
    FROM tablexemplo
) AS T
```

*Exemplo:* **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cda424/1)**

Comment: Lembrando que existe a ANSI EXTRACT que pode ser útil em Sistemas multi-bancos http://users.atw.hu/sqlnut/sqlnut2-chp-4-sect-4.html

Comment: Solução perfeita! muito obrigado!

Answer (score 8):

### O Problema:

Para se calcular em anos, dias e meses separadamente, você precisa tomar alguns cuidados, pois alguns probleminhas passam despercebidos caso não se teste com datas variadas.

Cálculos baseados em diferença de dias dão problemas pela diferença de dias em cada mês, e acabam retornando algumas coisas estranhas ao se converter pra AAAA MM DD, como erros de arredondamento e números quebrados.

Além disso, quando você tem duas datas na ordem certa, porém com mês final menor que inicial, e/ou dia final menor que o dia inicial, precisa lembrar de repassar dias e meses negativos para os meses e anos do cálculo, e adicionar os dias do mês na quantidade certa. Estas duas datas mostram bem o problema, teste-as nas soluções propostas:

```
Data inicial | Data final 
-------------+-------------
2013-09-30   | 2014-06-28
```

Uma solução seria usar uma série de `IF`s para isso no `SELECT`, porém, teria que se calcular corretamente as condições para o número de dias de cada mês. É possível resolver com vários `IF`s, e apesar de complexo o resultado, funciona bem. Felizmente o MySQL tem várias funções internas para lidar com datas, nos poupando da parte chata.

### A Solução:

O MySQL tem a `DATE_SUB()`, que já leva em consideração os dias de cada mês, e para usá-la corretamente, bastou extrair separadamente os dias, depois os meses e finalmente os anos da data inicial, representada por `CURRENT_DATE` ou `CURDATE()`.

Evitei o uso do `NOW()` para não ter que lidar com horas, minutos e segundos.

Segue a query:

```
SELECT
   @calculo :=
      DATE_SUB( DATE_SUB( DATE_SUB( CURRENT_DATE,
               INTERVAL YEAR( DataDeAdmissao ) - 1 YEAR
            ), INTERVAL MONTH( DataDeAdmissao ) - 1 MONTH
            ), INTERVAL DAY( DataDeAdmissao ) - 1 DAY
      ) AS Calculo,

   DataDeAdmissao,

   CURRENT_DATE AS Hoje,

   CONCAT(
         YEAR( @calculo ) - 1,' ANOS, ',
         MONTH( @calculo ) - 1,' MESES E ',
         DAY( @calculo ) - 1,' DIAS'
      ) AS Extenso

   FROM TabelaExemplo
```

> Teste o funcionamento neste **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/93154/1)**

### Observações importantes:

- Para não mostrar "0 ANOS", "0 MESES" ou "0 DIAS", basta usar o seguinte ajuste:

  No lugar de `YEAR( @calculo ) - 1,' ANOS, '`
  use `IF( YEAR( @calculo) > 1, CONCAT( YEAR( @calculo ) - 1,' ANOS, ' ), '' )`

  A mesma lógica pode ser usada para o plural. `1 ANO`, `2 ANOS` ...
- Se você for usar uma coisa dessas para cálculos trabalhistas, por exemplo, não queira resolver isso num SELECT. Cálculo trabalhista envolve uma série de parâmetros extras, e realmente a contagem tem que ser feita seguindo as peculiaridades da legislação.
- O conceito de diferença de dias, anos e meses não é tão absoluto como parece. Quando você fala de "dois anos de diferença", ou "três meses de diferença" pode estar considerando ou não os dias extras dos anos bissextos, depende como vai ser usado este valor. Não tem uma solução que sirva para todos os casos. Analise sempre a aplicação final que você vai dar ao valor obtido (parece estranho, mas é isso mesmo).

  Exemplo: "um ano" antes de um 29 de fevereiro é primeiro de março, ou 28 de fevereiro do ano anterior?
- Ainda baseado no ponto anterior: lembre-se que você pode **inverter a ordem das subtrações no select acima**, para primeiro tratar dos anos, depois dos meses e dos dias. Dependendo do critério desejado, isso pode fazer diferença em datas críticas e casos extremos.
- Não foram adicionadas proteções adicionais contra datas invertidas e valores absurdos apenas para não complicar a resposta. Provavelmente estes casos e possíveis erros seriam tratados na aplicação principal, de qualquer forma.

Answer (score 7):

Fazendo uso das funções do MySQL para manipulação e/ou recolha de datas, podemos calcular as diferentes diferenças de forma obter os valores separadamente.

Assumindo que o valor da coluna DataAdmissao é "2010-04-07" e a data actual é "2014-06-29":

- Com a função [`YEAR()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_year) conseguimos extrair o ano de uma data. Com a função [`CURDATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curdate) podemos obter a data actual:

  ```sql
  SELECT YEAR(CURDATE()) - YEAR(DataAdmissao)

  -- Resultado:
  -- 4
  ```
- Com a função [`TIMESTAMPDIFF()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff) podemos calcular a diferença entre duas datas, obtendo o resultado consoante a primeira instrução, neste caso `MONTH` para ficarmos com os meses:

  ```sql
  SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(
           MONTH,
           DataAdmissao + INTERVAL TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, DataAdmissao, CURDATE()) YEAR,
           CURDATE()
         )

  -- Resultado:
  -- 2
  ```

  <sup>Á data em questão calculou-se e adicionou-se a diferença em anos para que o número de meses seja reduzido.</sup>
- O mesmo método aplica-se para obter os dias, onde indicamos à função `TIMESTAMPDIFF()` que queremos o resultado em dias:

  ```sql
  SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(
            DAY,
            "2010-04-07" + INTERVAL TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, "2010-04-07", CURDATE()) MONTH,
            CURDATE()
          )

  -- Resultado:
  -- 22
  ```

  <sup>Á data em questão calculou-se e adicionou-se a diferença em meses para que o número de dias seja reduzido.</sup>

Como pretendes obter uma frase, podemos depois usar a função [`CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) para juntar tudo:

```sql
SELECT
  CONCAT (
    YEAR(NOW()) - YEAR(DataAdmissao),
    " anos, ",
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(
      MONTH,
      DataAdmissao + INTERVAL TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, DataAdmissao, CURDATE()) YEAR,
      CURDATE()
    ),
    " meses e ",
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(
      DAY,
      DataAdmissao + INTERVAL TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, DataAdmissao, CURDATE()) MONTH,
      CURDATE()
    ),
    " dias."
  ) as meuTexto

-- Resultado:
-- 4 anos, 2 meses e 22 dias.
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dd13b/1/)