# Tempo de Casa em SQL (Anos, meses e dias)

Tags: sql, sql-server, tsql

Preciso criar uma função em SQL que retorne o tempo de casa do funcionário, exemplo: **anos**, **meses** e **dias**

Até o momento consegui trazer os **anos** e **meses**, porém não consegui chegar a lógica do **dia** ainda, alguém pode me ajudar ?

```
DECLARE @DTINI DATE, @DTFIM DATE

SET @DTINI = '2015-12-17'
SET @DTFIM = '2016-03-10'

SELECT  CAST(DATEDIFF(DAY,@DTINI,@DTFIM)/365.25 AS INT)     ANOS,
        CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY,@DTINI,@DTFIM)/30  > 11 THEN 0
         ELSE DATEDIFF(DAY,@DTINI,@DTFIM)/30        END MESES
```

Comment: PL-SQL no SQL Server? Você está usando SQL Server + T-SQL ou Oracle + PL-SQL?

Comment: PL-SQL no SQL Server.

Comment: Paulo, você tem certeza? Até onde vai meu conhecimento ninguém chegou a portar o PL/SQL para o SQL Server... Será que você não está usando T-SQL sem saber? O código tem cara de T-SQL

Comment: Realmente, é um T-SQL, me perdoe pela confusão.

Comment: Já perguntado e respondido em [Calcular diferença entre Datas no SQL Server, com saída Anos, Meses e Dias](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/22850/calcular-diferen%c3%a7a-entre-datas-no-sql-server-com-sa%c3%adda-anos-meses-e-dias)

Answer (score 2):

Verifique se seria está a lógica:

```
DECLARE @DTINI DATE, @DTFIM DATE

SET @DTINI = '2015-10-17'
SET @DTFIM = '2016-12-17'

SELECT 
    CAST(DATEDIFF(DAY, @DTINI, @DTFIM) / 365.25 AS INT) AS ANOS,
    DATEDIFF(d, @DTINI, @DTFIM) - 365 * CAST(DATEDIFF(DAY, @DTINI, @DTFIM) / 365.25 AS INT) AS DIAS,
    CASE 
        WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY, @DTINI, @DTFIM) / 30 > 11 THEN 0
        ELSE DATEDIFF(DAY, @DTINI, @DTFIM) / 30
    END AS MESES
```

Multiplico a quantidade de dias de um ano pela quantidade de ANOS sendo assim se for 0 anos não diminui os dias do DIAS se for 1 ano diminui o 365 fazendo assim com que fique 1 ano e 20 dias etc...

Answer (score 1):

Paulo, esta função pode ter problemas com anos bissextos, tente fazer o seguinte:

```
DECLARE @DTINI DATE, @DTFIM DATE, @ANO INT, @MES INT, @DIA INT

SET @DTINI = '2015-01-01'
SET @DTFIM = '2016-12-31'

SET @ANO = DATEDIFF(YEAR, @DTINI, @DTFIM)
SET @DTINI = DATEADD(YEAR, @ANO, @DTINI)
SET @MES = DATEDIFF(MONTH, @DTINI, @DTFIM)
SET @DTINI = DATEADD(MONTH, @MES, @DTINI)
SET @DIA = DATEDIFF(DAY, @DTINI, @DTFIM)

SELECT @ANO AS ANO, @MES AS MES, @DIA AS DIA
```

Answer (score 0):

***SQL Criação da Tabela***

---

```
CREATE TABLE [tablexemplo](
    [DataAdmissao] [date] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY];
INSERT INTO tablexemplo values('2010-01-30');
INSERT INTO tablexemplo values('2010-02-28');
INSERT INTO tablexemplo values('2010-03-30');
INSERT INTO tablexemplo values('2010-06-29');
INSERT INTO tablexemplo values(GetDate());
```

---

***SQL***

```
  SELECT 
    DataAdmissao,
    CASE WHEN Mes < 0 THEN
        (Ano - 1)   
    ELSE
        Ano
    END as Ano,
    CASE WHEN Mes < 0 THEN
        (Mes + 12)  
    ELSE
        Mes
    END as Mes,
    Dia
FROM (
    SELECT 
        DataAdmissao, 
        Ano, 
        CASE WHEN Dia < 0 THEN
            (Dia + 30)  
        ELSE
            Dia
        END as Dia,
        CASE WHEN Dia < 0 THEN
            (Mes - 1)   
        ELSE
            Mes
        END as Mes
    FROM (
        SELECT DataAdmissao, 
            (YEAR(GETDATE()) - YEAR(DataAdmissao)) as Ano,
            (MONTH(GETDATE()) - MONTH(DataAdmissao)) as Mes,
            (DAY(GETDATE()) - DAY(DataAdmissao)) as Dia
        FROM tablexemplo 
        ) AS T
    )T1
```

### SqlFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0e783/1

[Fonte](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/22850/calcular-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-datas-no-sql-server-com-sa%C3%ADda-anos-meses-e-dias)

Answer (score 0):

Fiz conforme o exemplo do durtto e ficou assim:

```
DECLARE @DTINI DATE, @DTFIM DATE
DECLARE @DIA INT, @MES INT, @ANO INT


SET @DTINI = '2014-10-31'
SET @DTFIM = '2018-11-30'

SET  @ANO = (YEAR(@DTFIM) - YEAR(@DTINI)) 
SET  @MES = (MONTH(@DTFIM) - MONTH(@DTINI)) 
SET  @DIA = (DAY(@DTFIM) - DAY(@DTINI)) 

IF @DIA < 0
    BEGIN
        SET @DIA = @DIA + 30
        SET @MES = @MES - 1
        IF @MES < 0
                BEGIN
                    SET @ANO = @ANO -1
                    SET @MES = @MES + 12
                END  

    END
ELSE IF @MES < 0
                BEGIN
                    SET @ANO = @ANO -1
                    SET @MES = @MES + 12
                END             

PRINT @ANO 
PRINT @MES 
PRINT @DIA
```