# PEGAR O MÊS ATUAL SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Olá!
**Como faz para pegar o mês atual no SQL Server ?**
Estou fazendo o seguinte CASE :

```
WHEN PP.DATAINICIAL is not null AND PP.DATAFINAL is not null THEN 'FINALIZADO'
WHEN PP.DATAINICIAL is not null AND PP.DATAFINAL IS NULL THEN 'PENDENTE'
WHEN PP.DATAINICIAL (MÊS ATUAL) then 'ENTRADA'
ELSE 'NÃO IDENTIFICADO'
```

Quando a data inicial é igual ao mês atual ele recebe o argumento 'ENTRADA'

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Calcular diferença entre Datas no SQL Server, com saída Anos, Meses e Dias](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/22850/calcular-diferen%c3%a7a-entre-datas-no-sql-server-com-sa%c3%adda-anos-meses-e-dias)

Answer (score -1):

Se precisa do mês em formato de numero, você pode usar o
(select convert(char(2),(getdate()),101))